# SAS histogram using aggregated data

Tags: sas

I usually use proc gchart since it is reasonably easy to create pretty charts, but as far as I can understand using either gcart or univariate I have to have one row per observation.

How could I create a histogram using aggregated data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gchart ... vbar /freq=NumberOfObservationsInClass .